# I want to pass a variable in CFSTR?

Tags: iphone, cfstring

In following coding, i want to pass variable via CFSTR, how can I ?

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef address = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABDictionaryPropertyType);
// Set up keys and values for the dictionary.

CFStringRef keys[5];

CFStringRef values[5];

keys[0] = kABPersonAddressStreetKey;

keys[1] = kABPersonAddressCityKey;

keys[2] = kABPersonAddressStateKey;

keys[3] = kABPersonAddressZIPKey;

keys[4] = kABPersonAddressCountryKey;

values[0] = CFSTR("Wiztech, 208/B Clifton Center, Karachi");

//values[0] = CFSTR(address1); I want to pass address1 which is NSString, how can I?

values[1] = CFSTR("");

values[2] = CFSTR("");

values[3] = CFSTR("");

values[4] = CFSTR("");
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just cast it like:

```
NSString * yourThing = [NSString stringWithString:@"blah blah"]
values[0] = (CFStringRef)yourThing;
```

NSString and CFString are interchangeable (subject to being cast). Dont forget to retain/release too